How to connect Laravel storage with Storj.io bucket for file uploads like S3?
I’m trying to connect my Laravel application to a Storj.io bucket for file uploads using Laravel’s built-in storage system (Storage::disk()), similar to how I would connect to AWS S3. However, I haven’t been able to get it working, and I’m stuck.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
1. Environment Configuration:
I added the following details to my .env file:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my_access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my_secret_key
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=my_storj_bucket
AWS_ENDPOINT=https://gateway.storjshare.io
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true

I updated the s3 driver in config/filesystems.php:
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
],

I wrote a simple file upload function:
$path = $request->file('file')->store('uploads', 's3');


You are using the s3 storage functionality to connect to storage bucket that is not a  Amazon S3 storage, so its not strange that it is not working. In this case you will have to write the integration yourself (or search a package that does the integration if that exists)

Why no debugging logs? Please update your question adding all errors you see....
